# Changing locale action causes 404

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, locale

I'm trying to build a function into my spring app that changes the local to switch languages. I thought my logic is right but I guess not. When I click the **set locale** button it rends me to a 404

The user will select a button in the JSP as shown in Allbeers.jsp

```
   <form action="setLocale">
        <select name="locale">
            <option value="en"><spring:message code="lang.english"/></option>
            <option value="es"><spring:message code="lang.spanish"/></option>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="button.setLocale"/>"/>
    </form>
```

the form act will bring you to the controller beerController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "setLocale", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView SetLocale(@RequestParam("locale") String locale, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
    LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, StringUtils.parseLocaleString(locale));
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/beer");
}
```

my bean localeResolver in my config.xml

```
 <bean id="localeResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_IE" />
</bean>
```

here is all my controller code in case it is needed to know how I map the methods

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/beer")
@SessionAttributes("beer")
public class beerController {

      @Autowired
    beerService service;

    @RequestMapping("")
    public ModelAndView getBeers() {
        //int x = Integer.parseInt("abc");
        return new ModelAndView("/Allbeers", "beerList", service.getAllBeers());
    }
@RequestMapping(value = "setLocale", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView SetLocale(@RequestParam("locale") String locale, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    {
        LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, StringUtils.parseLocaleString(locale));
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/beer");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The form action in the jsp didnt have the correct path

```
 <form action="/Assignment3/beer/setLocale">
        <select name="locale">
            <option value="en"><spring:message code="lang.english"/></option>
            <option value="es"><spring:message code="lang.spanish"/></option>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="button.setLocale"/>"/>
    </form>
```